# How to install sweetalert2 to laravel 10 vite

Tags: php, laravel, npm, node-modules, sweetalert2

I can't have problem w sweetalert2.

I have error in console:

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (list:121:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.7.0.js:5135:27)
    at elemData.handle (jquery-3.7.0.js:4939:28)
```

It concerns this part of code (index.blade.php):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
            $('.delete').click(function() {
                Swal.fire("hello");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In others files I have:
app.blade.php:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            @yield('javascript')
    </script>
```

bootstap.js

```
    import 'bootstrap';
    try {
        window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
        window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
        window.Swal = require('sweetalert2');
    
        require('bootstrap');
    } catch (e) {}
```

package.json

```
    {
        "private": true,
        "type": "module",
        "scripts": {
            "dev": "vite",
            "build": "vite build",
            "watch": "vite build --watch",
            "prod": "vite production"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
            "axios": "^1.1.2",
            "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
            "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.5",
            "sass": "^1.56.1",
            "vite": "^4.0.0"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "jquery": "^3.7.0",
            "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
            "sweetalert2": "^11.7.16"
        }
    }
```

app.scss

```
    @import 'sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss';
```

I install sweetalert2 using command:

> npm install sweetalert2

And this add new folder sweetalert in node_modules

When I use npm audit I have:

```
> npm audit report                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                         sweetalert2  >=11.6.14                                                                                                      
sweetalert2 v11.6.14 and above contains potentially undesirable behavior - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-mrr8-v49w-3333
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`                                                                                   
Will install sweetalert2@11.6.13, which is a breaking change                                                                
node_modules/sweetalert2                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                            
1 low severity vulnerability                                                                                                

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

but npm audit fix --force doesn't help

I try to use npm run dev and npm run watch too.

Edit:
I add this to app.blade.php

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

And it's help.

But, Can it be made to work without it?

Answer (score 1):

Use imports.

**bootstrap.js**

```
import jQuery from "jquery";
window.$ = jQuery;

import {popper} from "@popperjs/core";
window.popper = popper;

import {swal} from "sweetalert2";
window.swal = swal;
```